# Replace linux-raspberrypi with core/linux-rpi-legacy?

Tags: archlinux-arm

When I ran 'pacman -Syu' today on an rpi3 Arch-Linux installation, the following question
was asked: Replace linux-raspberrypi with core/linux-rpi-legacy? [Y/n]
Is this a simple renaming or is this an
important change impacting the system's future?

Comment: The issue is indeed mentioned in the [Open News Page](https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=15688&p=68072) thread and also on [Gripes about linux-rpi rebrand](https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=15689&p=68080), although I still haven't figured out what they're planning to do. I'd suggest to wait until this blows over and see if the issue persists?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Always look first into the forums:
https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15683

Comment: `The requested topic does not exist.` - do you happen to know the title of the thread you wanted to link to?

Comment: @ckujau I have posted an answer with the text and a link that worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Although the other answer was first, here's the relevant information from the forum:

> Raspberry Pi kernel rename coming soon
>
> Post by graysky » Sun Nov 28, 2021 12:20 pm
>
> In a rebranding move, we
> are changing the names of the two kernel packages for the RPi series
> of devices to more adequately represent the intended platform.
>
> linux-raspberrypi --> linux-rpi-legacy (RPi 1, 2, Zero, Zero W)
>
> linux-raspberrypi4 --> linux-rpi (RPi 3, 4, 400, and Zero 2 W)
>
> Once the new packages are built and hit your mirror, pacman should
> automatically handle it by asking you if you would like to replace the
> old package with the new one. Say Y to proceed.

The full name of the thread is "Raspberry Pi kernel rename coming soon"

The link on the forum for me is [this](https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15691)